# How can I remove all but last 10 characters in a group of files

Tags: batch-file, rename

How can I rename a group of files like

```
admin_ball_126608454.gma
another_thing_384157357.gma
```

to

```
ds_126608454.gma
ds_384157357.gma
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this script. It prompts you every time a file is about to be renamed You could eliminate this behaviour by removing the IF..ELSE clause from the script. The prompt was added to ensure you don't accidentally renamed folders or rename files with any wrong name

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /P path=Enter the path please :
ECHO The Path entered is %path%. 
CD %PATH%
ECHO Current Directory is %CD%
FOR /R %path% %%G IN (*.*) DO (
SET name=%%~nG
SET last=!name:~-10!
SET/P cho="ECHO File !name!%%~xG will be renamed to ds_!last!%%~xG Do you want to continue (y/n) ?"
IF !cho!==y  (REN "!name!%%~xG" "ds_!last!%%~xG") ELSE (ECHO Not Renamed)
)
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use substring or regex.  Append `-whatif` to make a test run - but without changing anything. I'm sure there are a lot more ways to do this in PowerShell

#### <sub>Substring</sub>

```
Dir "C:\yourfolder"  | ren -NewName {
    "ds" + $_.basename.substring($_.basename.length-10,10) + $_.extension
} -whatif
```

#### <sub>Regex using lookahead</sub>

```
Dir "C:\yourfolder" | ren -NewName {$_.name -replace "^.*(?=.{10}\.)","ds"}
```

We use a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) `(?= )` to match everything `^.?` before the last 10 characters `.{10}`

#### <sub>Regex using capture groups</sub>

```
Dir "C:\yourfolder" | ren -NewName {$_.name -replace '(.*)(.{10}\.)', 'ds$2'}
```

We use two [capture groups](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions#Example_-_Replace_With_Captures) `(...)(...)` and keep only the second one with `$2`. Here you have to use `'` instead of `"`